# Raspberry Pi Pico - Flashing program using Macbook

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to load a program on a Raspberry Pi **Pico**. Have loaded the standard blink program on it using USB connected to my Macbook and used Thonny to run and stop the program.
However if I disconnect the Raspberry Pi **Pico**, from the USB, the program disappears. I found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMZUZuytt7o) that shows how to make it work with a windows system, but if I try the same with Macbook does not work. It gets stuck at `Trying to connect to REPL`

Can someone suggest how we can flash the program on the Raspberry Pi **Pico** so that it stays whenever we connect it to power?

Here is the program I tried

```
import machine
import utime
led_onboard = machine.Pin(25, machine.Pin.OUT)
while True:
    led_onboard.value(1)
    utime.sleep(1)
    led_onboard.value(0)
    utime.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: Have got beyond the "Trying to connect to REPL". The problem I am having is that although I can copy the main.py program to /pyboard/main.py, when I disconnect and reconnect the program does not run. I have confirmed that the files I copy remain.

Comment: You may want to edit the question to reflect the updated situation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the suggested `RShell` solution using `pip install rshell`. However it does not seem to work on macbook very well when it comes to copying the program to the pico. So I tried an alternate REPL writer called `ampy`

To install ampy follow the guide on *https://github.com/scientifichackers/ampy*

`pip install adafruit-ampy`

In your shell go to the folder where the program is stored. Keep the file name as `main.py`

Run ampy using the command
`ampy -p /dev/cu.usbmodem0000000000001  put main.py`

The format is

ampy –p *[USB-Port]* put *[file to copy]*

The file is now copied into the board.

Now if you unplug and re-plug the power source the program in *main.py* would execute.